# How to show the data of the list outside of the area of ListView Builder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it technically impossible to show the data outside of the list? I searched through the internet but I couldn't get any answers at all smh -_-

I wanted to display the value of data rows of the list besides of the section `ListViewBuilder`.

Output:

> [ ListView Builder  Screen ]

> Name: You, Age: 20 Name: Him, Age: 20

An Output photo there.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFSnd.png)

```
String name = userList[index].name;
int? age = userList[index].age;
```

```
class _Passenger extends State<Passenger> {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();
  int currentIndex = 0;

  final form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool update = false;
  final User user = User(name: "", age: int.tryParse(''));
  List<User> userList = [
    User(name: "You", age: 20),
    User(name: "Him", age: 20),
  ];
  String text = '';
  int? number = int.tryParse('');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 550,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: userList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    String name = userList[index].name;
                    int? age = userList[index].age;

                    return SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                      child: Card(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text( "Name: $name    Age: $age"),
                              ))),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      Container( child: Text("Display the data here, How?") ),
      //Add Button
      Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 50,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(children: [
                        TextField(
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              text = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Age'),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              number = int.parse(value);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                userList.add(User(name: text, age: number));
                              });
                            },
                            child: const Text('Add'))
                      ]));
            },
            child: const Text("Add"),
          )),
    ])));
  }
}

class User {
  String name;
  int? age;
  User({
    required this.name,
    this.age,
  });
}
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to use a ListView.builder to display a list ?

Comment: What? I created the list, now I want to display both the list and the output that those data display outside of the ListView Builder,

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: My expected output below of the list is  Name: You, Age: 20 Name: Him, Age: 20
if you look at my photo I uploaded.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't wanna use ListView.builder.
I'm saying I need to display the data outside of the section ListView.builder as an additional display under the list screen, got it?

Comment: Like, if I wanna include ```String name = userList[index].name;``` and ```int? age = userList[index].age;``` in ```MaterialPageRoute```, how the hell can I do that?

So is it possible or not? If so then what's the solution?

Comment: Reread the edited question now. I changed the photo as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... if it's the same list, just add this :

Instead :

```dart
   Container( child: Text("Display the data here, How?") )
```

Do :

```dart
          SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: userList
                  .map((user) => Text("Name: ${user.name}, Age: ${user.age} "))
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
```

I added a `SingleChildScrollView` with horizontal scroll to avoid problems

To send the list of users to another page, just do :

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: const RouteSettings(name: "no-route"),
    builder: (context) => OtherPage(userList: userList),
  ),
);


class OtherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<User> userList;

  const OtherPage({
    required this.userList,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: userList
                    .map(
                        (user) => Text("Name: ${user.name}, Age: ${user.age} "))
                    .toList(),
              ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well then, If I want to route those data into the next page, what to do with this kind of navigation for those both data ```user.name``` and ```user.age```?


```Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) =>  NextPage(  ))```

Comment: I'm saying that ```String name = userList[index].name; int? age = userList[index].age;``` isn't in the list builder, is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to route all the list of users or only one user selected ?

Comment: Route all the list of users. But is ```Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) =>  NextPage(  ))``` gonna be out of the listview widget or?

Comment: For example, when I press Next Button which isn't in the code section of List Builder, the data of the list above there will be routed to another file.

Comment: I edited, do you want to do that ?

Comment: That's right, but I thought it'd need two variables above there like this
```Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute (builder: (context) =>  NextPage( data1, data2 ))```

Comment: Ok, that's why I got confused, because if you want to send two variables (name and age), it is because you chose only one user, and in case you want to send only the list, it is as I showed you. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the number of rows of your list, replace

```
Container( child: Text("Display the data here, How?") )
```

with

```
Text("Number of rows: ${userList.length}")
```

If you want to add something to the end of the list, you can do something like this:

```
ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                // everything else from your ListView.builder
        ),
        Text("Something different, inside scrollable list")
```

If that is not what you want, please edit the question and make clear what is intended results.

Comment: I'm not asking for the length, reread the edited question now. I changed the photo as well.